# Weight Painting / Armature Issue

Tags: armature, weight-painting

So I'm trying to move vertices by moving a bone, proportionally according to the weight painted.. but everything keeps on moving by the same amount, regardless of weight (as long as weight>0).

I have:

- only one group in the mesh (called "bone")
- painted weights in the mesh as in the picture
- one bone in the armature (called "bone")
- an armature modifier in the mesh

So now, when I move the bone, the mesh moves. But it doesn't move proportionally! All verts move, with the exception of the one without weight, but they all move the same amount.

What can I be doing wrong? Please help (I've been at this for hours!)

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way rigging is supposed to work, if your vertices are only part of one group, even with a weight of 0.001, they will move as much as vertices that are part of the same group with a weight of 1.

If they are part of several groups, the influence of the bone will be propotional to the weight. If a vertex has a weight of 1 in vertex group A and 1 in vertex group B, it will be moved equally by both the vertex groups. If a vertex has a weight of 0.1 in vertex group A and 1 in vertex group B, bone B will move it 10 times more.

Comment: That clears it up, thank you so much for the explanation!